# AlphaGo Improving Itself

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I've read a couple news articles about AlphaGo and they all mention that AlphaGo became better from first playing human games, then playing games against itself. One thing I am curious about is, how did AlphaGo improve itself? Does it modify variables in the code? Or does it change it's code completely writing it itself? Or did the creators add it? How does it actually learn? A generalised answer is fine as it's just for my general knowledge.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole concept, news articles tend to give a broad and sometimes misinformed understanding. Some clarity would be great or links to useful information.

Comment: I think the keywords you need to read up on are "supervised learning" and "unsupervised learning". But then I'm not familiar with AlphaGo, they may have used a completely different technique altogether.

Comment: AlphaGo used a plethora of learning algorithms, but the "playing against itself" part used a [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) algorithm

Comment: Machine learning programs store a training set, i.e. data descriptors with "decision" information, and use it to compute the parameters of a classifier. The general framework is well defined (preprogrammed training and classification algorithms), only the data set evolves. There is no intelligence in the box. In this particular case, the program played imaginary games and used the outcomes for self-training.

Comment: They use Reinforcement learning and Neural networks. By playing a lot of games the program "learns" which actions were good to take in which situations by keeping track of the results (value) of each played game (and step). Internally this is stored as a [policy](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node9.html) which is a list (or tree) of which action is best to take in a certain state.  See also [this related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201733/how-does-deep-learning-and-reinforcement-learning-combined-to-use-together).

Answer (score 0):

AlphaGo uses machine learning.

In Machine Learning you have a function (say `ax +b`) that gives you a result and you tune the parameters of that function (`a` and `b`) so that the result matches more and more the examples you have. In the case of AlphaGo they had 2 functions, one to pick the next move and and one to say who is winning, and both are very complex with many thousands of parameters.

When they played a game between two instances of AlphaGo they would record the result and use it as an example to train the functions, so that the next version plays even better.

There are great tutorials on the web on how machine learning works if you want to know more.